# How can I customize filter urls without an extension?

Tags: magento-1.9, filter

I want to customize and optimize my filter urls for SEO without using an extension.

Currently if I set up a filter I am getting urls like:

**www.mysite.de/electronics/cameras?color=40**,

but I want urls like:

**www.mysite.de/electronics/cameras/color/black**

It is possible with a few changes? I read that I can modify the getUrl function of local/Mage/Catalog/Model/Layer/Filter/Item.php for this, is it right?

Comment: Why the need to reinvent the wheel?  https://github.com/Flagbit/Magento-FilterUrls & app/code/local/Mage = bad practice.

Comment: thank you, but why is local/Mage bad practice?

Comment: More details: http://magebase.com/magento-articles/when-should-you-override-magento-core-files-in-app_code_local_mage/

Comment: @B00MER you should probably add this as an answer to get the site's answer ratios up. It seems a good one to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why the need to reinvent the wheel? 
http://github.com/Flagbit/Magento-FilterUrls

Also, app/code/local/Mage = [bad practice](http://magebase.com/magento-articles/when-should-you-override-magento-core-files-in-app_code_local_mage/).